# Why I get error about missing provider in Jest test run?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs, angular-router

Why I get this errors when I run Jest after adding RouterEffects to the application?

Error output (partly): No provider for Router!. Full output is available here: [gist with error output](https://gist.github.com/sharikovvladislav/df33d131ff66aaa9ceeb1ee98f6a1350)

Here is last commit after what I started to get this error: [change what break my tests](https://github.com/sharikovvladislav/ng2-diary-book/commit/a9cfddbae8c0a2aee44c7ce58b9d871aac733504). Here is effect file what I added: [effect file](https://github.com/sharikovvladislav/ng2-diary-book/blob/feature/add-breadcrumbs-module/src/app/core/effects/router.ts)

Yes I inject Router there. But why I get error? I have RouterModule in the CoreModule. I test a component from the DiaryModule. Here is how I configure the testing module:

```
.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [
    DiaryModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot({
      ...fromRoot.reducers,
      diary: combineReducers(fromFeature.reducers),
    }),
  ],
})
```

So why I get error? RouterModule must be included by this: TestingModule -> DiaryModule -> CoreModule -> RouterModule. According to specs (https://angular.io/api/router/Router) Router is a part of RouterModule. So why I get this error? Even if I import RouterModule I have same error: No provider for Router!. Why? How can I solve this?

I tried another setup. I tried this module configuration:

```
.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [
    MdIconModule,
    DiaryComponentsModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot({
      ...fromRoot.reducers,
      diary: combineReducers(fromFeature.reducers),
    }),
  ],
  declarations: [
    MyDairyPageComponent,
    CommonShowIfLoggedInComponent,
    NotLoggedInComponent,
  ],
  providers: [DialogFactoryService],
})
```

Look how first configuration is better then second. Second one is working, I don't get same error as in first configuration. Why? I have module and I want to test component from that module. All what I want is to import module that contains component.

Comment: why do you have no delcarations in the first setup? and where do you inject `Router`?

Comment: @MaximKoretskyi I have all of these import and declarations inside DiaryModule. routermodule imported too in diary module. In browser everything OK OK, but not in tests.

Comment: I see, sorry, can't help. It requires debugging. Maybe if you could reproduce the problem [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ezqijs) I could take a look

Comment: I have repro in the repo. If you want I can prepare branch for it. Is it OK for you to clone, yarn install and npm test?

Comment: If nope, do you have any examples of writing angular plunkers with tests?

Comment: yeah, prepare a branch, I'll try to take a look

Comment: Here is branch: https://github.com/sharikovvladislav/ng2-diary-book/tree/repro-for-router-problem (repro-for-router-problem). 1. Clone 2. yarn install 3. npm test. Tell me please if you will get any problem, I will fix it.

Comment: Also you can watch the result here https://circleci.com/gh/sharikovvladislav/ng2-diary-book/127

Comment: sorry, man, I've spent 30 minutes trying to find a way to debug tests with jest but to no avail. I've never before worked with it. I don't have any more time

Comment: Hm. I will try to prepare code for you. Would be nice if you can watch it later. I will try to message you somehow. By the way: using jasmine everything is ok =)

Comment: Thank you very much for your time!!!!1

Comment: What node version do you have? I found that: https://twitter.com/cpojer/status/897864538221158400. Trying this at the moment

Comment: Yes it is ok to debug Jest on node 8.4.0. Can I get your attention again please? :)